# Getting unOrdered data even after applying Indexing in firestore after certain range

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

When I add data in Firestore after applying indexing (auto generated indexing by clicking on link in Android studio terminal) . My data get added and queried in the way I wanted until my document lrNo (a field in my document in Firestore) reaches 999. After that the data started adding at the beginning which ruins my descending order. In my case my lrNo and document id both are same. The result I get is in same order as my  document id displayed in the image which I don't want; I wanted it to be in descending order.

[image]

I have already generated index by clicking on the link below .

```
Error: FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here:
https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/[PROJECT-NAME]/firestore/indexes?create_compo
site=[INDEX EXAMPLE] (failed-precondition)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:49397/dart_sdk.js:4776:11)
    at handleThenable
    (http://localhost:49397/packages/firebase/src/storage.dart.lib.js:3237:21)
    at handleThenable.throw (<anonymous>)
    at onError (http://localhost:49397/dart_sdk.js:35663:38)
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:49397/dart_sdk.js:35547:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (http://localhost:49397/dart_sdk.js:30969:50)
    at handleError (http://localhost:49397/dart_sdk.js:31482:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:49397/dart_sdk.js:31505:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:49397/dart_sdk.js:31366:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback
    (http://localhost:49397/dart_sdk.js:31401:31)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:49397/dart_sdk.js:35759:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:49397/dart_sdk.js:35765:13)
    at http://localhost:49397/dart_sdk.js:31707:9
```

Below is the code to sort and get data:

```
    var temp = await fireStore
        .collection("Admin")
        .where("phoneNo", isEqualTo: TextFieldData.phoneNo)
        .orderBy("lrNo", descending: false)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((value) => value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a field to store a numeric value, it should be a number type field, not a string.  Numbers and strings sort differently.  String always sort [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), which means they use the values of their characters from left to right, like a dictionary.  That makes "1000" less than "999", because "1" sorts less than "9".

Your lrNo field is a string, and you can tell from the screenshot because the value is in quotes.  It should be a number instead.  Make sure your code is writing the correct data type.

Comment: bro tnx 4 that this small mistake ruined my whole day.